# Is there a way to control which audio is sent to Bluetooth and which is sent to system speaker?

Tags: speaker, headset, bluetooth-audio

**Background info explaning why I want what I want**

I'm almost totally deaf. I have a Bluetooth-enabled hearing aid that is paired with my Droid RAZR (ICS 4.0.4). When any audio is played on the phone (ringer, phone call, media, etc) it triggers my hearing aid. The switch-over is not instant and I miss a few seconds of audio (plus I get a really loud, annoying beep from my hearing aid informing me that it is making the switch from external audio to BT audio).

As a result, text messages and other short audio notifications (like navigation speech) trigger my hearing aid, the loud beep occurs, the external mic is turned off, the BT connection is enforced, and then... nothing. In the time it takes for all that to occur, I've missed whatever the audio input was.

**TL;DR**

I'd like to be able to tell my phone to direct text messaging, ringer, and other audio playback (navigation) to the system speaker and to continue to direct in-call and media playback to my paired, BT-enabled hearing aid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What make of hearing-aid are you referring to? I know Phonak has it in their range but that requires wearing a necklace with BT attached to it to pair it up...

Comment: fwiw, I wear a Phonak, but do not bother with the necklace for BT pairing for extra features as that would be a temptation for me to attempt hacking on it and make things worse as the hearing aid itself costed an arm and a leg, not worth hacking :D

Comment: Maybe someone can check, but I think I saw options like this on CyanogenMod 7 (at least for notification and ringtone), but that was over a year ago, I could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try [BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono),   maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that app isn't even remotely close to what I'm trying to do. I already have audio streaming to my BT-hearing aid, what I want is to control WHICH audio is sent.